# Changing file type icons with Assogiate

Tags: 10.10, nautilus, icons

I am Ubuntu 10.10 (64 bits) user and I would like know how to make Nautilus display a customized svg icon for all my latex files.

Searching for this information, I discovered that the program *Assogiate* is capable of to replace the default icon assigned to the latex files by a customized svg icon.
For the other hand it seems that there is a bug related to *Assogiate* and Nautilus.

1-Could you point me any workaround to solve the problem between *Assogiate* and Nautilus ? 
2-Is there another program that could be use to this end ?

Thanks.

PS: After change the latex file icons using *Assogiate* it is possible to see the new icon in Thunar.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure, if this is what you want. I understood you want to change the icon for latex files, right?

So all you have to do is, to change the icon for latex files in your icon-set.
The icon for the application files are stored under /usr/share/icons/... or ~$/icons..

For example, if you are using Faenza icon set you'll find the icons in

```
/usr/share/icons/Faenza/mimetypes/scalable
```

Just replace the latex icon with your favourite one. Hope, this helps.

Comment: Hi bdr529, I follow your suggestion but I guess that latex files on my system are not associated to any icon. I copied my favorite icon in the folder /usr/share/icons/gnome/scalable/mimetypes/ with the name tex.svg but this was not enough. Next I used assogiate but still not working. Do I need to update some something to the system recognize the file tex.svg as an icon ?