# How do I change a specific file type Icon in Nautilus?

Tags: 11.04, nautilus, icons

How can I change a specific file type icon on Unity for example .css .php files icon?

[image] [image]

Comment: but Assogiate doesn't work with Nautilus and 11.04, unfortunately

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [Assogiate](http://ubuntugenius.wordpress.com/2009/11/19/create-your-own-file-types-in-ubuntu-with-assogiate/). See also [Changing file type icons with Assogiate](https://askubuntu.com/q/31601/19490).

Comment: Well, you still use Nautilus in Unity, ain't you?