# How do I change the icon for a particular file type?

Tags: nautilus, icons, mime-type

I'm trying to change the icon for `application/x-hwp` files. I've added the icons to the proper places, and checked it with assoGiate (after reading [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/q/49042/13398)). It shows that my desired icon is associated with the file type. Nevertheless, Nautilus is still showing the old icon. How can I make Nautilus show the correct icon?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/39139/how-to-change-the-icons-of-multiple-files-from-terminal

Comment: @Rinzwind: Thanks. Unfortunately, that link solves a different problem. It's based on changing the icons of individual files. I want to change the default icon for all files of a given type.

Comment: Are you using a custom icon theme? That could be interfering with the icon that is supposed to show up.

Comment: I'm using the stock Ambiance theme. Anyway, it shouldn't matter, because to my knowledge no icon themes cover this file type. I'm just getting the icon that appears by default when Nautilus doesn't know what other icon to display. Additionally, icon themes are hierarchical, so if an appropriate icon can't be found in the current theme, the hierarchy will be searched, ultimately culminating with the hicolor theme. My icons are installed in both the ubuntu0mono-dark and hicolor themes.

Answer (score 31):

Here is a set of instructions that should get you a custom icon for hwp files.

Open a terminal :

- Check the MIME type exists : `grep 'hwp' /etc/mime.types`

  if you get an output resembling `application/x-hwp hwp` skip the next step.
- Create the MIME type `sudo -H gedit /etc/mime.types` and add the line `application/x-hwp hwp`
- Add the icon *(which must be called `application-x-hwp.svg`)*:

  ```
  sudo cp PathToIcon/application-x-hwp.svg /usr/share/icons/gnome/scalable/mimetypes
  ```

  *(don't forget to replace PathToIcon)*

*Got the information from [here](http://wiki.ubuntu.com.cn/UbuntuHelp:AddingMimeTypes)*

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I haven't had a chance to try it thoroughly yet (so far, no success), but I'm awarding the bounty because the other suggestions haven't worked and I won't have a chance to work on this any more before the bounty expires.

Comment: You maybe should check if your icon theme inherits from gnome (most icon themes do). You will find that information in index.theme located in the directory of your icon set

Comment: You also need to check `~/.local`.  For example `~/.local/share`, which mimics the folder `/usr/local/share`.   Your locally installed application (i.e. application for you only, not other logins), may have their properties there.  Edit similar files, for example, `~/.local/share/icons/XXXX/XXXX`

Comment: @danjjl: What do you mean with (don't forget to replace PathToIcon) ?

Comment: @JoKalliauer in the command to copy the icon to `/usr/share/... `. I refer to `PathToIcon`. This needs to be substituted with the path to the icon on your PC. _(if you think this could be formulated more clearly don't hesitate to propose an edit)_

Answer (score 20):

The main trick is to find out correctly where the actual icons are located.
In order to determine that let's analyze HTML icons. Naming convention for the icons is the same as for the MIME-type, only `/` is replaced with `-` and no capital letters are allowed. I.e. MIME-type, say, `text/x-changelog` will have the icon named `text-x-changelog.svg` (or `png`). MIME-type for HTML is `text/html`. So its icon will be `text-html.*` If we run the command

```
find /usr/share/icons/ -type f | grep 'text-html\.'
```

we will get several places where these icons are placed:

```
/usr/share/icons/Humanity/mimes/
/usr/share/icons/gnome/NNxNN/mimetypes/
/usr/share/icons/HighContrast/scalable/mimetypes/
```

If we visit each of them with Nautilus we'll see, that `Humanity/` folder contains our current icons, `gnome/` - some older ones. `HighContrast/` doesn't interest us. So in order to change some icon we should replace the icons located in `Humanity/` folder.
Also notice that `text-html.svg` icons which are scalable and should have been placed into `scalable` subfolder (that should be logical) are placed into the folders for different sizes instead, in the same way as raster PNG files.

After replace of the icons (in all subfolders according to their sizes) with the desired ones icon cache should be updated:

```
sudo gtk-update-icon-cache /usr/share/icons/Humanity
```

That's it.

There's another way to determine the precedence of icon schemes - to check their `index.theme` files. If we look inside `/usr/share/icons/Humanity/index.theme`, we'll see:

```
Inherits=gnome,hicolor
```

This means that icons from `gnome` and `hicolor` folders will have less precedence than the ones from `Humanity`. This is explained [here](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/icon-theme-spec/icon-theme-spec-latest.html).
Strangely enough, Nautilus doesn't obey these inheritance rules. When I added new MIME-type, I tried placing its icons into `/usr/share/icons/gnome/`, `/usr/share/icons/hicolor`, `~/.local/share/icons/hicolor`, updating icon database on each step - all in vain. These icons were displayed properly in `assogiate` on the first tab, but never in Nautilus. But when I placed them into `Humanity` folder and updated icon database, they appeared at once.

**N.B.** All this applies to the default icon theme. If you use some custom icon theme, you should check where the *actual* icons are located and add/change icons there instead. Also in newer distributions these inheritance rules may change. Then you should locate the new folder which stores the actual icons (if it is not `Humanity` anymore) as explained previously.

Comment: You also need to check `~/.local`.  For example `~/.local/share`, which mimics the folder `/usr/local/share`.   Your locally installed application (i.e. application for you only, not other logins), may have their properties there.  Edit similar files, for example, `~/.local/share/icons/XXXX/XXXX`

Answer (score 0):

I hope you tried logout and login to refresh icon cache.

See also if your icon is available in proper size (the one you're using to display file type in nautilus).

You also might missed running `gtk-update-icon-cache`.

Try this tutorial: http://swik.net/Ubuntu/Only+Ubuntu/How+To+Change+File-Type+(mimetype)+Icons+in+Ubuntu/chcrf

Try to manually create icon.theme, here is an example I have from awn:

```
[Icon Theme]
Name=awn-theme

Directories=scalable

[scalable]
Size=48
MaxSize=256
Context=Apps
Type=Scalable
```

Manual is here: http://live.gnome.org/GnomeArt/Tutorials/IconThemes

Comment: I've installed a 48x48 icon and set Nautilus to 100%, which uses 48x48. No dice. Re-logging in makes no difference. Running `gtk-update-icon-cache` has no effect.

Comment: I updated my answer, did it help?

Comment: I haven't manually created an icon theme, because I don't want a new theme. I just want the icon to go into the hicolor theme, because that's the base of all the icon themes. Creating a new theme will defeat my purpose.

Comment: Both the swik.net and live.gnome.org links in this answer are dead.