# Change filetype icon (Pcmanfm LXDE)

Tags: nautilus, icons, thunderbird, pcmanfm

I've been trying to change the icon for the filetype *.eml (message/rfc822) within PcManFm (file manager of LXDE) but after severall hours and many lines read and tried, I still cannot find a working solution, neither for PcManFm nor for Nautilus.

I have a 48x48 png file called *thunderbird.png* which I would like to make the image of the *.eml files

I've tried with:

**xdg-icon-resource**

```
xdg-icon-resource install --context mimetypes --mode user --size 48 ./thunderbird.png message-rfc822
```

**assoGiate**

changed the default icon for the message/rfc822, but it did not changed anything nor in PcManFm nor in Nautilus

**and [this other solution](https://askubuntu.com/a/56725/39101) for Gnome/nautilus**

didn't worked also...

Does anyone have a clue/idea of how to solve this?

I'm trying to show a person that everything he does with windows can be done with linux, and he works a lot with email_files.eml that in windows show up with the thunderbird icon...

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way of installing icons in Lubuntu is by going to `Customize Look and Feel`:

[image]

And these sets of icons are not file-browser-specific, they would be the same in all file browsers.

As icon sets come as deb files you might try an icon-set that contains the image for your file, extract the deb, replace the file related to what you want with the one you want instead, archive as tar.gz and than replace extension to deb, and install this deb.

But I am afraid I do not know how to do this specifically for the file type you mentioned, because I am not familiar with that file. But you should know more about that.

Also a problem might be the fact that these images in the deb file are svg, not png images.

**Instead of trying all this**, maybe you should consider that the best way to deal with your friend would be not to show him that Ubuntu can do **the same things** as Windows, but that it can do **a lot more**, only differently. For example **changing all icons very easily**.

Why bother to add single file-type icon when you can get unitary-style icon sets of superior quality?

For example these monochrome ones:

[image]

or

[image]

More [HERE](http://gnome-look.org/index.php?xcontentmode=120x121)

You might find that an icon-set you like will also change the image of the type of file you talk about to something better than you had imagined.

Comment: Thanks for the answer cipricus - I'll try it when I have another chance in that computer :) Good looking desktop you built for yourself :)