# How do I change the icon for .doc, .odt, .ods .xls .ppt filetypes from LibreOffice icon to OpenOffice icon?

Tags: unity, nautilus, icons, libreoffice, openoffice.org

The "problem" I am facing is that I uninstalled the Ubuntu 14.04's default LibreOffice and installed OpenOffice , but the .doc, .xls, .odt, .ods .... files even though they open by default with OpenOffice, their icon is still the original LibreOffice icon. I was searching every where to find the LibreOffice Icons but could not find it in /usr/share/icons in any subfolders, I am running out of ideas.

Where are these settings stored?

I tried the following:

1.
Right clicked on a .doc file and click Properties and than click on it's icon image and change it, but this only changes the specific files icon not the icon for all the .doc files.

2.
After uninstalling LibreOffice and installing OpenOffice I created a new user, and logged in as that but even the new user was seeing the icons as LibreOffice default icons. Which make me think that the settings are rather system wide than user specific settings.

3.
Was trying `assogiate` but it is not available in Ubuntu Software Center anyomore , --maybe is not for Unity desktop.

4.
The solution given at [Change filetype icon (Pcmanfm LXDE)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/166584/change-filetype-icon-pcmanfm-lxde) is referring to an other desktop environment "LXDE", --- I think.

5.
The "solution" given in [How to change the icons of multiple files from terminal?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/39139/how-to-change-the-icons-of-multiple-files-from-terminal) is rather a workaround, because as far as I can tell he is modifying the icon for each file,folder individually. I would like this change to happen everywhere in the system and even for new files.

Thank you,

Comment: more similar to http://askubuntu.com/questions/166584/change-filetype-icon-pcmanfm-lxde and also http://askubuntu.com/questions/39139/how-to-change-the-icons-of-multiple-files-from-terminal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The icons for a file type have nothing to do with what software you are using (unlike Windows). It is your icon theme that matters.

On Ubuntu, this means it *has to* be under either `/usr/share/icons` or `~/.icons`. You will need to edit some files like `/usr/share/icons/<your-icon-theme>/mimes/16/application-vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation.svg`. Here, `<your-icon-theme>` could very likely be `Humanity`.

Comment: I don't have much time to check now. but There is a file as you suggested in the /usr/share/icons/Humanity  location. It is a Symlink pointing to a libre office image. I will check when I got a few minutes, and accept your answer if this works. Cheers anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I started with [Darshak Parikh](https://askubuntu.com/users/314018/darshak-parikh)'s suggestion.
And realised I have to replace the symbolic links (symlinks) in the `/usr/share/icons/<your-icon-theme>/mimes/<your icon size>`    folder. In my case `<your-icon-theme>` was the default Ubuntu Unity theme `Humanity` and as for `<your icon size>` I just replaced sizes `16` `32` `48` `128` `256`.

Here is a part of the code which can help you do the same, You would consequently have to replace 16 with 32, 48, 128, 256 to fit your resolution I guess. To be honest I didn't tried just replacing the 16 size folder, I did it all and then a computer restart ( -- I didn't knew which service to restart)

```
wget  -O ~/Dowloads/ "http://svgicons.o7a.net/unofficial/OOoBase.svg"
wget  -O ~/Dowloads/ "http://svgicons.o7a.net/unofficial/OOoCalc.svg"
wget  -O ~/Dowloads/ "http://svgicons.o7a.net/unofficial/OOoDraw.svg"
wget  -O ~/Dowloads/ "http://svgicons.o7a.net/unofficial/OOoFormula.svg"
wget  -O ~/Dowloads/ "http://svgicons.o7a.net/unofficial/OOoImpress.svg"
wget  -O ~/Dowloads/ "http://svgicons.o7a.net/unofficial/OOoWriter.svg"

sudo cp ~/Downloads/OOoBase.svg /usr/share/icons/Humanity/mimes/48/OOoBase.svg
sudo cp ~/Downloads/OOoCalc.svg /usr/share/icons/Humanity/mimes/48/OOoCalc.svg
sudo cp ~/Downloads/OOoDraw.svg /usr/share/icons/Humanity/mimes/48/OOoDraw.svg
sudo cp ~/Downloads/OOoFormula.svg /usr/share/icons/Humanity/mimes/48/OOoFormula.svg
sudo cp ~/Downloads/OOoImpress.svg /usr/share/icons/Humanity/mimes/48/OOoImpress.svg
sudo cp ~/Downloads/OOoWriter.svg /usr/share/icons/Humanity/mimes/48/OOoWriter.svg


sudo cp /usr/share/icons/Humanity/mimes/16/application-vnd.oasis.opendocument.presentation.svg  ~/Downloads/presentation-16.svg
sudo rm /usr/share/icons/Humanity/mimes/16/application-vnd.oasis.opendocument.presentation.svg  
sudo ln -s /usr/share/icons/Humanity/mimes/48/OOoImpress.svg /usr/share/icons/Humanity/mimes/16/application-vnd.oasis.opendocument.presentation.svg 

sudo cp /usr/share/icons/Humanity/mimes/16/application-vnd.oasis.opendocument.spreadsheet.svg  ~/Downloads/spreadsheet-16.svg
sudo rm /usr/share/icons/Humanity/mimes/16/application-vnd.oasis.opendocument.spreadsheet.svg  
sudo ln -s /usr/share/icons/Humanity/mimes/48/OOoCalc.svg /usr/share/icons/Humanity/mimes/16/application-vnd.oasis.opendocument.spreadsheet.svg 

sudo cp /usr/share/icons/Humanity/mimes/16/application-vnd.oasis.opendocument.database.svg  ~/Downloads/database-16.svg
sudo rm /usr/share/icons/Humanity/mimes/16/application-vnd.oasis.opendocument.database.svg  
sudo ln -s /usr/share/icons/Humanity/mimes/48/OOoBase.svg /usr/share/icons/Humanity/mimes/16/application-vnd.oasis.opendocument.database.svg

sudo cp /usr/share/icons/Humanity/mimes/16/application-vnd.oasis.opendocument.drawing.svg  ~/Downloads/drawing-16.svg
sudo rm /usr/share/icons/Humanity/mimes/16/application-vnd.oasis.opendocument.drawing.svg  
sudo ln -s /usr/share/icons/Humanity/mimes/48/OOoDraw.svg /usr/share/icons/Humanity/mimes/16/application-vnd.oasis.opendocument.drawing.svg

sudo cp /usr/share/icons/Humanity/mimes/16/application-vnd.oasis.opendocument.formula.svg  ~/Downloads/formula-16.svg
sudo rm /usr/share/icons/Humanity/mimes/16/application-vnd.oasis.opendocument.formula.svg  
sudo ln -s /usr/share/icons/Humanity/mimes/48/OOoMath.svg /usr/share/icons/Humanity/mimes/16/application-vnd.oasis.opendocument.formula.svg

sudo cp /usr/share/icons/Humanity/mimes/16/application-vnd.oasis.opendocument.text.svg  ~/Downloads/text-16.svg
sudo rm /usr/share/icons/Humanity/mimes/16/application-vnd.oasis.opendocument.text.svg  
sudo ln -s /usr/share/icons/Humanity/mimes/48/OOoMath.svg /usr/share/icons/Humanity/mimes/16/application-vnd.oasis.opendocument.text.svg
```