# Komodo Edit does not show correct file association icons

Tags: icons, file-association, komodo-edit

the main problem which I'm tring to resolve is that my Komodo Edit text editor all of a sudden began to show Mathematica icon for every file (yesterday I just had installed Mathematica 10). This is very annoying, and I will be very grateful to anyone who will be able to solve this.

[image: wrong file association icons]

What I have found for now is that this is somehow related to the global settings, because when I forbid any access to a directory where Mathematica is installed, that is Komodo has no way to get an icon from this directory, but still shows it for every file.

Also I tried to remove the profile directory for Komodo - no result.

**So the question is**:

does anyone know where Komodo-Edit or other program can get this icons? They are not stored in its installation directory and the access to the mathematica directory is forbidden completely (`000`).

Could anyone help me with this? How can I get rid of these Mathematica icons?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, after intermittently being struggling for five month with this, I've figured this out.

In short: one need to delete a hidden file `~/.local/share/icons/.png` which is created by a Mathematica installation script.

With a bit more explanation: after I gave up to find the reason for this problem from a Komodo side, I tried to find how icons for mime types are managed in Ubuntu. So, with the help of Google, stackexchange and [danjjl's answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/52138/how-do-i-change-the-icon-for-a-particular-file-type) I decided to search in the `.local/share/icons` directory, where I immediately spotted this hidden file.