# Where Can I Find the "Show Applications" Icon From My Icon Theme?

Tags: gnome, icons, icon-themes

[image: Desktop Screencap]

I'm currently using the paper icon theme (https://snwh.org/paper), and trying to find the "Show Applications" icon, so that I can replace it.

The above picture shows the icon as used by the dash-to-dock GNOME extension.

This is a similar question to: [How to change Show Applications button on Gnome dash](https://askubuntu.com/questions/787873/how-to-change-show-applications-button-on-gnome-dash) but the answer to that question does not apply to anything other than the default GNOME icon.

After searching for the icon in question in the `/usr/share/icons/paper/scalable/actions` directory (the file path comparable to the answer from the above question, but for the paper theme) all I could find was a symbolic style icon that isn't the one used here, and when I searched through other folders from the paper icon theme, I was only able to find icons that were similar, but the 6 holes were not transparent, so those must not be the right icons either.