# How to fix incorrect "Show Applications" button icon?

Tags: icons, themes, gnome-shell, ubuntu-dock, icon-themes

I am on Ubuntu 18.04 with GNOME. I am currently using the Pop theme, but I don't think that matters much.

[image]

Contrary to the question and answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/787873/how-to-change-show-applications-button-on-gnome-dash), the `view-app-grid-symbolic.svg` icon is not what is currently being used.

[image]

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/aIP91.jpg)

Comment: Have you rebooted once after changing the icon theme to Pop?

Comment: Yes I did, but the problem still stays. (In fact just to make sure, I rebooted now once again)

Comment: Could you find the location of the icon that is currently being used somehow? Try searching with the term "ubuntu" in the `/usr/share/icons/Pop` directory.

Comment: Nope didn't find it anything exactly like that, but there were a few using different colours.

Answer (score 0):

The problem fixed itself. I don't know what exactly triggered it, but maybe it was about updating the system. All I ran was `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade`. So if anyone else faces this problem, updating might be worth a shot.