# How to add an image icon to default executable applications ?

Tags: icons

I want  to change the default rombus shaped icon with a new icon ,is there a way to do this ?

Comment: You need to edit the .desktop file.

Comment: See this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/52138/how-do-i-change-the-icon-for-a-particular-file-type tl;dr you'll have to go to your current icons directory and replace `application-x-executable` file(s) in `./mimetypes`.

Comment: @MichaelBay I think OP is not asking for changing the icon of one application, but the default icon for executables (application-x-executable).

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is create a `.desktop` file somewhere like your home folder.  Next, add these lines:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=<Name of your Application>
Exec=/path/to/executable
Icon=/path/to/icon/file
Comment[en_US]=<What you want the mouse over text to be>
```

Comment: I think OP is not asking for changing the icon of one application, but the *default icon for executables* (application-x-executable).