# How can I change app icons all at once?

Tags: 17.10, icons, themes

Is it possible to change many icons at the same time? I'm using Ubuntu 17.10

[image: many rtf files highlights]

Comment: Those look like data files and not application starters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than try and change the icon for all of the files, change the icon associated with that file type (apparently rtf).

Here's a set of instructions to do just that:

(found here: [How do I change the icon for a particular file type?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/52138/how-do-i-change-the-icon-for-a-particular-file-type) )

---

Here is a set of instructions that should get you a custom icon for hwp files.

Open a terminal :

- Check the MIME type exists : `grep 'hwp' /etc/mime.types`

  if you get an output resembling `application/x-hwp hwp` skip the next step.
- Create the MIME type `sudo -H gedit /etc/mime.types` and add the line `application/x-hwp hwp`
- Add the icon *(which must be called `application-x-hwp.svg`)*:

  ```
  sudo cp PathToIcon/application-x-hwp.svg /usr/share/icons/gnome/scalable/mimetypes
  ```

  *(don't forget to replace PathToIcon)*

*Got the information from [here](http://wiki.ubuntu.com.cn/UbuntuHelp:AddingMimeTypes)*

---

Note you need to use svg files for the icon in question, you may need to convert your image depending on its type.