# How to dissociate an app from a file type icon

Tags: nautilus, icons

Some softwares associate a specific icon with a file type (e.g., installing Mathematica gives all *.nb files a new icon). Sometimes this can lead to minor annoyances for generic file types such as *.dat, as a program can associate its icon with the dat file type even if most of the dat files are in reality have nothing to do with the program. There also appears to be some precedence issues where some applications override the default icon of a theme but some applications don't, which I don't understand.

I've tried resetting the default application to no avails. I'm also aware of the question: [How do I change the icon for a particular file type?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/52138/how-do-i-change-the-icon-for-a-particular-file-type) but I'm not sure how the answers there help with my problem. Any suggestions?

Comment: *How* did you reset default application? Elaborate on cases where this is a problem. Nautilus file manager allows to set the default application by which its opens files through Properties - Open with tab.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome:)

You should be able to do so by removing the association in `/etc/mine.types`

Let's start by making sure the extension has an association:

```
grep 'dat' /etc/mime.types
```

Since you have Mathematica installed, it should have two lines similar to this (but with mathematica listed there)

```
application/x-python-code                       pyc pyo
text/x-python                                   py
```

I would remove the dat on both via a text editor, running sudo, for example

```
sudo vim /etc/mime.types
```

Save and restart and voila!

(Invert the help from here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AddingMimeTypes This was my source)

Answer (score 0):

It should be just a matter of heading into the properties of a file concerned, and changing the default application to open that type of file.

- Right-click a file that is being opened with the wrong application
- Select "Properties"
- On the "Open With" tab, select the application you wish to be the default.

From now on, the application will open in the application you designated when launching it from the file manager. You can still conveniently right-click and select "Open with other applications" for times where you want to open the file in another way.

Comment: Yes it is what I tried and it did not change the file icon.

Comment: To be clear, it is not an issue of the association with a different application, but an issue of the icon used? That is what the title of the question suggests, but then the body of your question is talking about file associations. Slightly confusing.