# How do I change icon of a file type globally and permanently?

Tags: files, icons

For example, I have several Octave script files (.m extension) and they all have the ugly and somewhat disguising "text file" icon. Ok, they're indeed text files, but so are C/C++ files, Fortran files, Python files and... regular text files. There's a nice icon for Octave that I would like to associate with Octave file types but I don't see how. If I right-click a .m file and select "Properties" I am not allowed to change the icon. And even when I'm able to do that (with some other file type) I can only change the icon of that specific file, not all other files of that type.

In the past, there was a program called `assogiate` which seems to be obsolete/nonfunctional presently.

Anyway, new Ubuntu releases come, old releases go and an easy and automatic way to associate a file type to a specific icon still does not exist. Or does it?

Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I change the icon for a particular file type?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/52138/how-do-i-change-the-icon-for-a-particular-file-type)

Comment: @JoKeR, I was trying _exactly_ that when I got your reply. No, it isn't working so far (I'm following the tips in the most voted answer), and I wouldn't expect that a 9-year old answer would still work or be valid. There must be something else involved. Will keep trying.

Comment: check the next answer below most recent