# How to set the icon for a file extension, in a portable way, without sudo

Tags: nautilus, icons, mime-type, xdg

I am creating an app that wants to **install an icon** for an application-specific extension (`.crystalopen`), in a way that works not just on Ubuntu/GNOME but also is **portable to other desktop environments** like KDE.

The app installs itself to `~/.local/bin` (rather than to `/usr/bin`) so that root permissions are not required. Therefore I would like the icon **installed within `~/.local/`** if possible.

#### What I've tried

I **register a MIME type** (`application/vnd.crystal-opener`) for the `.crystalopen` extension by creating an `application-vnd.crystal-opener.xml` that looks like:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<mime-info xmlns='http://www.freedesktop.org/standards/shared-mime-info'>
    <mime-type type="application/vnd.crystal-opener">
        <comment>Crystal Opener</comment>
        <glob pattern="*.crystalopen"/>
    </mime-type>
</mime-info>
```

and installing it with:

```
$ xdg-mime install --mode user application-vnd.crystal-opener.xml
```

which internally:

1. copies it to `~/.local/share/mime/packages`, creating any intermediate directories as needed; and
2. runs `update-mime-database ~/.local/share/mime/` to update `~/.local/share/mime/mime.cache`.

I **verify that the MIME type is registered** by creating a non-empty<sup>1</sup> file with the file extension and querying its MIME type:

```
$ echo OPEN > OPEN.crystalopen
$ xdg-mime query filetype OPEN.crystalopen
application/vnd.crystal-opener
```

or equivalently (on GNOME):

```
$ gio info OPEN.crystalopen | grep standard::content-type
  standard::content-type: application/vnd.crystal-opener
```

I **create an icon image** with the correct filename for the MIME type, `application-vnd.crystal-opener.svg`:

```
<svg height="128" width="128">
  <ellipse cx="43" cy="32" rx="32" ry="32" style="fill:red" />
  <ellipse cx="84" cy="32" rx="32" ry="32" style="fill:green" />
</svg>
```

The [Icon Theme Specification](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/icon-theme-spec/icon-theme-spec-latest.html) says that I should be able to install such an image in the "hicolor" theme which all other themes inherit from. But that does not seem to work. In particular if I do the following:

```
$ sudo cp application-vnd.crystal-opener.svg /usr/share/icons/hicolor/scalable/mimetypes
$ sudo update-icon-caches /usr/share/icons/*
```

then the icon for the `OPEN.crystalopen` file in the Files app does NOT change to the new image.

Perhaps the Files app does not implement theme inheritance correctly?<sup>2</sup>

Instead I identify which specific theme is the system's default theme and install the icon there, which doesn't feel very reliable or portable:

- I **identify candidates for the system default theme** by looking for the icon of a common MIME type like `text/html`:

```
$ find /usr/share/icons -name 'text-html.*'
/usr/share/icons/Yaru/... (10 lines)
/usr/share/icons/HighContrast/... (1 line)
/usr/share/icons/Humanity/... (7 lines)
```

- Ultimately `Humanity` turned out to be the system default theme for this system (Ubuntu 23).
- First I try to install the icon to the machine-wide theme directory:

```
$ sudo cp application-vnd.crystal-opener.svg /usr/share/icons/Humanity/mimes/256
$ sudo update-icon-caches /usr/share/icons/*
```

- That works, successfully updating the icon for the `OPEN.crystalopen` file in the Files app to the new image.
- However I want to **install to the user's theme directory** rather than to the machine-wide theme directory, so I do this instead:

```
$ mkdir -p ~/.local/share/icons/Humanity/mimes/256
$ cp application-vnd.crystal-opener.svg ~/.local/share/icons/Humanity/mimes/256
$ sudo update-icon-caches /usr/share/icons/*  # not sufficient to update: ~/.local/share/icons/*
```

- That also works, successfully updating the icon for the `OPEN.crystalopen` file in the Files app to the new image. (Although unfortunately a `sudo` is required to update the machine-wide icon cache for the icon to show up immediately, before the next logout & login.)

#### The big question

**How can I install an icon to a user theme directory such that the icon for related files in the Files app updates to the new image, in a reliable and portable way** that will work not just in GNOME but also in KDE and other desktop environments?

In particular, is it possible to install an icon to the `~/.local/share/icons/hicolor` theme which is documented in the [Icon Theme Specification](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/icon-theme-spec/icon-theme-spec-latest.html) as being always available?

---

<sup>1</sup> An empty file will often be recognized as a MIME type like `application/x-zerosize` rather than any new custom MIME type that is registered.

<sup>2</sup> "Nautilus doesn't obey [theme] inheritance rules" according to https://askubuntu.com/a/752316/1724736

Answer (score 0):

Since inheritance of icons between themes didn't seem to be working correctly, I just wrote a script to install my apps icon to *all* themes on the system. Messy but effective.

Please see [the 124 lines of custom install code](https://github.com/davidfstr/Crystal-Web-Archiver/blob/147adc7bea1fa8d278258e75be3e51fd26892bfa/src/crystal/install.py#L107-L230) I used to achieve this.